# use ActionBarSherlock library, error after use sherlock as library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My own project is using **Android 2.1 API 7**.

To implement action bar, I use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library. I imported the **sherlock** library into my Eclipse as an existing project. For **sherlock**, the target platform is **Android v3.2 API 13** .

Then, I added **sherlock** as a library project to my own project. Then, I notice there is no `R.java` file under `gen/` folder in my own project, and I got error like following in eclipse console:

```
JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-436230d/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.

JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-436230d/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:48: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarSize'.

JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-436230d/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:49: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarStyle'.

...
```

I thought it was probably because of the **sherlock** should use higher version API, so I tried to set target platform to **4.03 API 15** on **sherlock** project. But it does not help.

Anyone use sherlock has experienced the same error?? How can I solve this problem?

**P.S.** my own project manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="my.frag.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does your *own* project target API level 7, or is that it's min SDK value? Try setting it's target to level 15 as well

Comment: @ Espiandev, I don't understand you. What's the point to set my own project to level 15?? I mean sherlock is supposed to be used to have native action bar in old version API like my project (API 7), if I set my own project to use API 15, what's the point to have the sherlock library on the earth then???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the build target to API13 on your own project.

The minimum API level your app works on is defined by android:minSdkVersion in your manifest, NOT the build target.

Setting the build target to API13 does NOT make the ActionBar available on 2.1 devices, and that is why you have ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: So, if I set build target to API 13 on my own project, can my own app be run on Android 2.1 device? and how to set build target ?

Comment: Yes, your app will still be able to run on 2.1. What version you support from is defined by android:minSdkVersion in your manifest. You should be able to change build target from project properties in Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Both your app and the library need to be compiled with Android 3.2 for proper support.

You can set your `minSdkVersion` in the manifest as low as '4', however, to still support back through Android 1.6. The `targetSdkVersion` also **must** be set to '11' or higher.

Take a look at the samples in the `samples/` folder of the project for an idea of how this is done.

Comment: So, if I set build target to API 13 on my own project, can my own app be run on Android 2.1 device?

Comment: Provided the `minSdkVersion` is '7' or below, yes.

Comment: Would be good to mention this on the [usage](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) page

Comment: The site is being redone for version 4 over the next two weeks and will have **much** better and more comprehensive documentation, including key facts like this.

Comment: @JakeWharton i am trying this on an emulator. I dont have API 15 installed on my emulator, hence i am using API 14 as build target. But the library i downloaded is 4.1.0. It gives me the same error as in the question. Is this because i dont have API 15 installed or something else?